# Want weekly difference between two field when year will change

Tags: sql-server

I am creating the following query for calculating weekly difference of disk space, but when year will change then it will display wrong data, how can I handle this?

```
select T.*, [Weekly Diff] = T.FreeGB - T1.FreeGB, [Monthely Diff]= T.FreeGB - T2.FreeGB, T1.*,T2.* From 
(SELECT  *, [Week No]= datepart(WEEK,CreatedDate),[Month No] = datepart(MONTH,CreatedDate), [Year] =datepart(YEAR,CreatedDate) FROM  Disk_Space ) T 
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT  *
,[Week No]= datepart(WEEK,CreatedDate),[Month No] = datepart(MONTH,CreatedDate), [Year] =datepart(YEAR,CreatedDate) FROM  Disk_Space ) T1 
on T1.[Week
 No] = T.[Week No] - 1 and T.Year = T1.Year and T.ServerName =     BT1.ServerName and T.Drive = T1.Drive
```

Comment: Calculate DateDiff between two days, Divide it by 7, it's absolute weeks, and compare DayOfweek of startDate with DateDiff % 7 in order to calculate remaining week (if existed)

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by taking like following

select T.*, [Weekly Diff] = T.FreeGB - T1.FreeGB , [Monthely Diff]= T.FreeGB - T2.FreeGB
From 
DISK_SPACE T
LEFT JOIN  DISK_SPACE T1 
on DATEDIFF(week,T.createddate,T1.createddate)=1 and  DATEDIFF(day,T.createddate,T1.createddate)=7 and  T.ServerName = T1.ServerName and T.Drive   = T1.Drive